# Row level formula - Syntax error. Extra IF

Tags: formula, error, compile-error

I'm looking to group company segments by using a Country lookup. I have a string that looks up a specific country (i.e. DE) and then a CONTAINS function which is looking up more than one Country (GB or IE). The DE formula works fine on its own, so does the GB/IE formula but when grouped together, I get an EXTRA IF error. Can someone help?

```
IF(
    CONTAINS('GB|IE', COUNTRY), 
    IF(
        EMPLOYEES >= 750,
        'Enterprise', 
        IF(
            EMPLOYEES >= 201,
            'MM', 
            IF(
                EMPLOYEES >= 80,
                'GRB', 
                IF(
                    EMPLOYEES >= 20,
                    'SB',
                    'ESB'
                )
            )
        )
    ), 
    NULL
)
IF(
    COUNTRY = 'DE',
    IF(
        EMPLOYEES >= 1000,
        'Enterprise',
        IF(
            EMPLOYEES >= 201,
            'MM',
            IF(
                EMPLOYEES >= 46,
                'GRB',
                IF(
                    EMPLOYEES >= 11,
                    'SB', 
                    'ESB'
                )
            )
        )
    ), 
    NULL
)
```

Comment: As a general tip, the first thing that you should do when running into issues with formulas is to [format them according to best practice](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_formula_best_practices.htm&type=5) as I have done for you here. In short... put each function onto its own line, and indent an extra level every time you see an open parenthesis. Doing so makes it a lot easier to spot subtle errors (like missing commas and extra/missing parenthesis).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma after

```
IF(EMPLOYEES >= 20,'SB','ESB')))), NULL )
```

Answer (score 0):

You usually can't just butt two formulas end-to-end and have it work.
The

```
IF(...)
IF(...)
```

construction is not valid syntax. Formulas need to end up providing a single value in the end, and each of your top-level `IF()` functions provide their own value. So the `IF(COUNTRY = 'DE', ...)` is the "extra IF" the error is complaining about.

In some situations, you could use an operator to take those two results and combine them into a single result, e.g.

```
/* Both IF()s return a single integer */
/* We use addition to take those two intermediate results, and */
/*   combine them into the final, single result */
IF(COUNTRY = 'DE', 1, 0) + IF(CONTAINS('DE|IE'), 2, 0)
```

In your case, what you want to do is to nest your second `IF()` into the "expression if false" part of the first `IF()`. After all, you don't want to return null unless the Country is neither 'GB', nor 'IE', *nor 'DE'*. The Country being neither 'GB' or 'IE' is not sufficient for you to give `null` as the result.

```sql
/* You only want a single top-level IF() */
IF(
    CONTAINS('GB|IE', COUNTRY),
    /* begin value/expression when true */
    IF(
        EMPLOYEES >= 750,
        /* and I'm not typing out the rest */
    ),
    /* end value/expression when true */

    /* begin value/expression when false */
    /* Instead of returning null, you need to further check to see if */
    /*   the Country is DE */
    IF(
        COUNTRY = 'DE',
        /* not gonna type out the rest of this either */
    )
    /* end value/expression when false */
)
```